# Scaling of data for ReLU and Tanh activation function

Tags: keras, neural-network

I have X_train and Y_train. X_train and Y_train have positive and negative values between (-2,2). Tanh activation function can have a value between (-1,1). Similarly, ReLU can have only a positive value greater than 1. If I want to scale the data for training using the deep neural network, shall I consider the activation function to decide the range of scaling?

Shall I scale my data to (-1,1) range if I am using Tanh activation function? Similarly, is it necessary to scale the data between (0,1) for ReLU activation function?

My unscaled data has both positive and negative numbers. I am using scaling between (0,1) and ReLU activation function. I am having a problem with the prediction for these settings. The solution diverges for (0,1) scaling with ReLU activation function. However, if I use (-1,1) scaling and ReLU activation function, the solution does not diverge. I also found that the scaling range is not affecting the prediction for tanh activation function.

Thank you.

Comment: If your train labels are between (-2, 2) and your output activation is tanh or relu, you'll either need to rescale the labels or tweak your activations. E.g. for tanh, either normalize your labels between -1 and 1, or change your output activation to 2*tanh.

Comment: Similarly, if I am using ReLU, shall I normalize between 0 and 1? Because my prediction diverges for ReLU activation function and scaling between (0,1). If I scale the data between -1 and 1, the ReLU activation function gives a decent prediction. Thank you.

Comment: For ReLU, in order to match the output range [0, infinity), you could sum 2 to your labels, so that they're in [0, 4]. If that's a sensible thing to do, that's another question

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to scale your data's values according to the nonlinearity. Just normalize your data and you should be fine.